# Chrome saying No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header, but the header is there

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, cross-domain, cors

This issue is mentioned in stackoverflow a dozen times already, but I have a different issue.

Chrome first makes an "OPTIONS" call to get the headers. As you can see, the correct headers are there.

[image]

For some reason, Chrome doesn't notice the header and cancels the actual request in the same manner that it would if the header wasn't there at all.

[image]

The page actually makes three calls and curiously, one of them works.

[image]

So the question is, when the header really is there, why does Chrome not respect it? What could I do to debug it?

**Update**

I tried adding `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` so now the header response from the OPTIONS call includes these response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

The result is the same.

**Setting the headers on the server side**

I set the headers on the serverside on every request (in Global.asax.cs Application_BeginRequest)

```
Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
```

**After investigating with Fiddler**

I looked through the raw request and response and found something surprising: The error is a simple HTTP 500 error from the application. Likely because the HTTP 500 error does not contain the right headers, Chrome doesn't show the returned error but instead shows the header related error.

**Answer**

So in conclusion, if Chrome gives says `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header` it might actually cover up a HTTP 500 error. This can be determined by checking request and response in Fiddler.

Comment: And the code...where is the code??

Comment: There should also be an `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header. I don't see it in the screenshot.

Comment: @RobertRozas Thanks. This issue is about why Chrome acts as it does, so I try to not include code that would take focus away from the issue I'm trying to understand. But I can post the raw requests/responses if needed?

Comment: @NielsBrinch Can you determine how the correct OPTIONS response differs from the invalid ones?

Comment: the client-side code is completely irrelevant in this case. however, some may be interested in seeing where/how you are setting the cors headers.

Comment: On every request in the entire web application, I set these headers. They are also visible in Chrome when investigating the response from the OPTIONS.

Comment: Does performing each of those requests one at a time change the result?

Comment: @KevinB good suggestion. I simplified it down to only trying to complete ONE of the failing requests. It's still failing, but very good idea to simplify it.

Comment: The same is happening with me! https://imgur.com/a/wOGmcQE

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If Chrome says `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header` it might actually cover up a HTTP 500 error. This can be determined by checking request and response in Fiddler.

Comment: THIS. Is that specified somewhere that a browser can do whatever on a 500?

Comment: The OPTIONS call is supposed to tell the browser that it is OK to go ahead with the real call. If the OPTIONS call fails, it ends up not giving this permission to the browser, which is essentially what the browser is reporting to you.

Comment: I think Chrome gives this error message wrongly in many cases, e.g. I had the wrong URL (correct server, wrong path, AJAX), and the options call contained all the headers, but the actual call failed with that error message. Hard to debug.

Comment: Yes very hard to debug. Not sure we can blame Chrome, because it literally does what it should, I guess. But it could be nice if it could share some more details about the failing OPTIONS. Not sure if they already improved this in the meantime actually.

Comment: I just got this case. The OPTIONS request succeeded but subsequent actual request s got 502/503 status.