# "Missing Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header" error while the header is present

Tags: google-chrome, fetch, http-status-code-500

My server correctly responds to preflight request with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header:

[image]

However, Google Chrome blocks the actual request: it shows 500 status and the console contains this error:

[image]

I tried changing `access-control-allow-origin: https://www.visualwatermark.com` to `access-control-allow-origin: *`. It didn't make any difference.

The problem appears in Google Chrome only. Firefox and Safari show no errors.

Is there something I'm missing? What should I change to make it work?

Comment: It is possible that the request might actually be a 500 error on the server side as well. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148106/chrome-saying-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-but-the-header-is-there)

Comment: @NikhilPandit thank you for the link. "Remote Address" field is empty for these requests, while there is an IP address for requests that actually failed.